# Syncing primary key between two tables stored in two different database

Tags: mysql

I have two MySQL database that contain two table, let's call them TABLE_A and TABLE_B. Both these tables have as fields `id` and `title`. Both databases are on the same server and the same user can access both.

Now, TABLE_A is a subset of TABLE_B for what concern the `title` field. It means that every `title` in TABLE_A is present in TABLE_B, too. While `id` fields of the two table are in no way related.

What I need is to sync `id` fields in TABLE_A with `id` fields in TABLE_B, according to the title, i.e. same `title`, same `id`. If it's not clear, I have to save TABLE_B `id` and override TABLE_A ones. And I DON'T have to add missing `title` from TABLE_B to TABLE_A.

Someone suggested to use a temporal table where to copy all TABLE_B fields in common with TABLE_A and then rename it as TABLE_A. I cannot follow this way, as TABLE_A actually has also other fields that I need to maintain. So, I cannot entirely drop the old TABLE_A.

Moreover, `id` is the primary key for both tables. It means that I cannot simply copy from TABLE_B to TABLE_A as the query will fail as soon as I try to change one `id` to another one that is already present in TABLE_A but linked to a different `title`.

I know how to write a Perl or PHP script to do it, but I would like to know if a pure MySQL solution exists.

Comment: You may wish to consider dropping the primary key, applying the updates, then re-add the primary key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this

```
CREATE TABLE TableA_TMP AS
SELECT * FROM TableA;

ALTER TABLE TableA_TMP ADD id_new int;

UPDATE TableA_TMP A INNER JOIN TableB B ON lower(A.title) = lower(B.title)
SET id_new = B.id;

RENAME TABLE TableA TO TableA_backup;    

CREATE TableA AS
select id_new as id, title,.... from TableA_TMP;
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't specify that TABLE_A has also other fields, different from TABLE_B, that I need to maintain. So, I just need to update the `id` fields. Edited the question to reflect this extra difficulty.

Comment: Your solution is perfect. I only had to do some syntax modification: `ALTER -> ALTER TABLE`, `RENAME -> RENAME TABLE` and in the UPDATE command I had to specify `A.id_new = B.id` otherwise MySQL complained about ambiguity for `id` as it was on both tables. Thank you very much.