# How to get the last number in a database column then increment it to include in another record?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database

I have been given the task of rewriting and old work application from classic .asp to ASP.NET that includes a database table that does not have an auto incremented primary key. We want to continue to use this table to maintain database integrity (it also has 80,000+ records!). The problem that I am running into is that I need to be able to pull the last item from the ID column of the database table regardless of how old the record is, increment that number and then include it in the new record to be inserted as the new record's ID number. How would I go about doing this? I have tried the ListItem, DataReader, DataTables, Generic Lists (as objects), and ArrayLists. I can pull the information and store it, but I cannot get the last item in the collection by itself. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
 protected void GetPrimaryKey()
 {
     string strSQL = "";

     try
     {
          OleDbConnection dbConn = new OleDbConnection();
          dbConn.ConnectionString = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionString["ConnectionString"].ToString();

          strSQL = "SELECT observationID FROM Observation";
          OleDbCommand myCmd = new OleDbCommand(strSQL, dbConn);
          OleDbReader reader;

          ListItem item;

          if (dbConn.State == ConnectionState.Colsed) dbConn.Open();
          reader = myCmd.ExecuteReader();
          while (reader.Read())
          {
               item = new ListItem();
               item.Text = reader["observationID"].ToString();
          }
          reader.Close();
          dbConn.Close();
          myCmd.Dispose();
      }
 }
```

Populating the list is where this code is at. The last item still needs to be found then incremented, and the returned to the submit button event handler that starts this whole process. I know this code is missing a lot, but I didn't want to send my entire commented mess. Again, any help is appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: order by observationID desc ?

Comment: I believe this answers your issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12537140/syncing-primary-key-between-two-tables-stored-in-two-different-database if not, you have to study your approach. Do not set an auto increment manually as it is the db job. If you need more details, let me know

Comment: Will this app be used by more than one user at a time? If so, the approach you are taking could easily lead to problems if two users execute this code against the database at the same time...what database are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP 1 ObservationId FROM Observarion ORDER BY ObservationId DESC
```

This will return the last row id

If more than one person try to get this value to insert, you will run into an issue where you end up with the same Ids, unless that column is unique and will throw an error.

To minimize issues, you can do an inline select in your insert statement.

```
INSERT INTO Observation (ObservationId) VALUES(SELECT TOP 1 (ObservationId + 1) As NewObservationId FROM Observation ORDER BY ObservationId DESC)
```

Not sure if my syntax is completely correct but it should lead you in the right direction.

Comment: The first part returned what I needed nicely, Thank you. I still have to work out the second part of your answer to increment. I have A LOT more than one field (70 or so) that I will be inserting into the record. It's an old, crazy database. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Try get the max observation ID in sql statement:
    SELECT MAX(observationID) FROM Observation

Then increment it.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MAX(observationID) FROM Observation
```

will always return the max value regardless of how old the record is

Answer (score 0):

just ask for next value autoincrement id from table:

```
SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('table_name');
```

enjoy xD.

Comment: hope you use SQL server

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do your query like this?:

```
SELECT Top 1 observationID FROM Observation order by desc
```

If you have some sort of parameters or configuration table, I suggest you store the last value there and retrieve/update it each time you do an insert. This will prevent any issues in case you have 2 or more clients trying to insert a new record at the same time.